# Issue Spring Boot Redis Multiple Applications Consuming Data

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I have two applications for which I am using Spring Boot and Redis.
From both the applications I am producing data to Redis.

**ISSUE** The data produced by Spring Boot Redis Application 1 is not available for Redis Application 2 and vice versa.

Redis is running locally.

Application YAML for both the applications is same -

```
spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
```

**Model Class**-

```
@RedisHash(timeToLive = 300,value = "alerts")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RedisModel {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String message;

    public RedisModel(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RedisModel{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Is there some parameters that are missed??
Please let me know in case of any queries.
Spring Boot - 2.2.0 Version.

Comment: Could you show some code. regarding the posting and consuming in topics

Comment: I am not using it as pub sub model...There is a model class with @Data annotation

Answer (score 0):

I think RedisConfiguration created by spring boot will namespace those cache keys with your application name. Therefore they won't be visible to each other. To get around this, you will have to do your own RedisConfiguration and disable the prefix via `disableKeyPrefix()` and then set your own prefix with `computePrefixWith(...)`.  Here is an example:

```
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager( RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory,
                                           ResourceLoader resourceLoader ) {
        RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder builder = RedisCacheManager
                .builder( redisConnectionFactory )
                .cacheDefaults( determineConfiguration( resourceLoader.getClassLoader() ) );
        List<String> cacheNames = this.cacheProperties.getCacheNames();
        if ( !cacheNames.isEmpty() ) {
            builder.initialCacheNames( new LinkedHashSet<>( cacheNames ) );
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

    private RedisCacheConfiguration determineConfiguration(
            ClassLoader classLoader ) {
        if ( this.redisCacheConfiguration != null ) {
            return this.redisCacheConfiguration;
        }
        CacheProperties.Redis redisProperties = this.cacheProperties.getRedis();
        RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .modulesToInstall( new SimpleModule().addSerializer( new NullValueSerializer( null ) ) )
                .failOnEmptyBeans( false )
                .build();
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping( ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY );

        ObjectMapper mapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .modulesToInstall( new SimpleModule().addSerializer( new NullValueSerializer( null ) ) )
                .failOnEmptyBeans( false )
                .build();
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping( ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY );

        GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer serializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer( mapper );

        //get the mapper b/c they registered some internal modules
        config = config.serializeValuesWith( RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer( serializer ) );

        if ( redisProperties.getTimeToLive() != null ) {
            config = config.entryTtl( redisProperties.getTimeToLive() );
        }
        if ( redisProperties.getKeyPrefix() != null ) {
            config = config.prefixKeysWith( redisProperties.getKeyPrefix() );
        }
        if ( !redisProperties.isCacheNullValues() ) {
            config = config.disableCachingNullValues();
        }
        if ( !redisProperties.isUseKeyPrefix() ) {
            config = config.disableKeyPrefix();
            config = config.computePrefixWith( cacheName -> cacheName + "::" );
        }
        return config;
    }
```

Comment: how will spring boot add it, and anyways i am able to fetch all keys but all are coming null

Comment: You would need to add this in your own @Configuration class to override the default Redis configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Redis is not very suitable for such a situation. A better solution would be using [Infinispan](https://infinispan.org/)